self_function can't work-- Can't subset columns past the end
There is dataframe raw_df as below:
library(tidyverse)

detail <- data.frame(cat = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"),
                     single_amount = c(1,3,7,2,1,4,6,1,6))
    
total <- data.frame(cat = c("a","b","c"),
                    total_amount = c(20,10,9))
    
raw_df <- detail %>% left_join(total, by = 'cat')

I defined self function allocate_data_m  to allocate total_amount when cumsum(single_data) is less then total_amount
allocate_data_m <- function(data, single_data, total_data) {
  out <- cumsum_single_data <- rep('NA', nrow(data))
  for (grouprow in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    
    cumsum_single_data[grouprow] <- 
      if_else(grouprow == 1, data[grouprow, single_data],
              cumsum_single_data[grouprow-1] + data[grouprow, single_data])
    
    out[grouprow] <- if_else(cumsum_single_data[grouprow] < data[grouprow, total_data], data[grouprow, single_data], 0)
  }
    out 
}

when run the allocate_data_m in mutate, the error occur. Anyone can help ? Thanks!
raw_df %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(amount_x_all = allocate_data_m(cur_data(), single_amount, total_amount))

The wished result as below , I am just wondering how the function allocate_data_m can't work.
raw_df %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(amount_x_all = if_else(cumsum(single_amount) < total_amount, single_amount, 0))


What is your expected output based on your test data?

You're trying to reference columns of your data that don't exist. The errors are in your first if_else statement.

@Edward  Thanks. In the mutate variable  single_amount is match with single_data which in the function . I am wondering , how the error occur and fix it ?

@Limey  Thanks, I edited the post and add the wished result

A minimal revision to your function:

Replace "NA" with NA. The former is literal character string, and the latter refers to the missing value in R.
Replace the first ifelse() with if (...) {...} else {...}. Otherwise, cumsum_single_data[grouprow-1] will throws an error when grouprow is 1.
Move the second ifelse() outside the for-loop, because it can be vectorizedly evaluated.

allocate_data_m <- function(single_data, total_data) {
  cumsum_single_data <- rep(NA, length(single_data))
  for (grouprow in seq_len(length(single_data))) {
    cumsum_single_data[grouprow] <- if(grouprow == 1) {
      single_data[grouprow]
    } else {
      cumsum_single_data[grouprow-1] + single_data[grouprow] 
    }
  }
  out <- ifelse(cumsum_single_data < total_data, single_data, 0)
  out 
}

raw_df %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(amount_x_all = allocate_data_m(single_amount, total_amount)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   cat   single_amount total_amount amount_x_all
#   <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 a                 1           20            1
# 2 a                 3           20            3
# 3 a                 7           20            7
# 4 b                 2           10            2
# 5 b                 1           10            1
# 6 b                 4           10            4
# 7 b                 6           10            0
# 8 c                 1            9            1
# 9 c                 6            9            6


Version 2
Use column names instead of column vectors. In this case, you must use column names with double quotes when you call allocate_data_m() inside mutate().
allocate_data_m <- function(data, single_data, total_data) {
  if(is(data, "tbl")) data <- as.data.frame(data)
  cumsum_single_data <- rep(NA, nrow(data))
  for (grouprow in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
    cumsum_single_data[grouprow] <- if(grouprow == 1) {
      data[grouprow, single_data]
    } else {
      cumsum_single_data[grouprow-1] + data[grouprow, single_data]   
    }
  }
  out <- ifelse(cumsum_single_data < data[, total_data], data[, single_data], 0)
  out
}

raw_df %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(amount_x_all = allocate_data_m(cur_data(), "single_amount", "total_amount")) %>%
  ungroup()


Thanks, this is grate !  in your code  "single_data"  and "total_data" are vector ?  In my code the are string for variable names, I don't know why it's can't  work

@anderwyang see my updated version 2. In that case you need to use column names surrounded with double quotes when you call allocate_data_m().

, thanks for your two versions,  very helpful !
